# Adding a controller explicitly to Owin self hosted WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I am doing some unit tests at the moment and part of the functionality is to make a call out to an API (it is a bit too much and too work sensitive to explain fully what it is doing here..).
Essentially, the API will receive a request, do some processing and forward that request to the relevant party.
I need to test that code, it is not viable to abstract it as it is pretty well abstracted already, but there are some hard dependencies on `HttpClient` that I cannot remove (at some stage, I will have to call it..).

I have been using Owin TestServer to create an in memory webapi server,

See Strathweb here: https://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/

David Whitney here: http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2015/01/07/testing-an-asp-net-webapi-app-in-memory/

and DontCodeTired: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/In-Process-Http-Server-for-Integration-Test-Faking-with-Owin-Katana-and-WebAPI

The problem I have, is that the WebApi server that I am creating to use to make the requests against, will auto detect the other API in the project and run requests against that, rather than using my unit test/mock controller.

How can I use the `HttpConfiguration` object, used in the `WebApp.Start<**Startup**>()` class to only use one controller? I mean this class:

```
internal class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnsureInitialized();
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

I am unclear how to resolve this as all examples online talk about mapping HTTP routes, rather than removing/manually adding routes.

If you have questions/criticisms please add a comment and I will update the question as best I can, I feel I may be limited a little in what I can post due to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution and I think a tidy one..

Based on a blog by Strathweb: https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

I have implemented a custom `DefaultAssembliesResolver` which excludes the assembly containing the other API Controller causing these issues.

The custom resolver:

```
public class MyAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        ICollection<Assembly> baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies.Where(x=>!x.FullName.Contains("<nameOfAssemblyToExclude>")));            
        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

then replace the default resolver in the startup class:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new MyAssembliesResolver());
```

This has allowed me to exclude the extra production `ApiController` (that I am trying to test), and only include my `ApiController` for the unit testing in memory Owin pipeline.